# What is the reason for this? (studying reasons for seg faults)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am just observing the reasons for segmentation fault. I malloced memory here but still it is giving seg fault. What might be the reasons for this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int **matrix,i,j;
    matrix = malloc(sizeof(int));
    **matrix = 10;
    printf("%d", **matrix);

}
```

Comment: Enable compiler warnings, and you will discover the problem.

Comment: Think of the type of matrix and what you are trying to do with **matrix = 10

Comment: main should return int. The rest is secondary.

Comment: **matrix is a pointer to pointer and you allocate memory for *matrix only. Not for **matrix, so you can not(should not) derefrence it(as you are doing in printf();).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matrix` is a pointer (it happens to be a pointer to a pointer to `int`), and you've allocated memory (though probably not enough) for it to point to.

`*matrix` is also a pointer (it happens to be a pointer to `int`), and you *haven't* allocated memory for it to point to, so `*matrix` contains garbage (or doesn't exist if your `malloc()` call didn't allocate enough memory).

So dereferencing `*matrix` has undefined behavior. You were lucky enough for the symptom to be obvious.

Why are you allocating `sizeof(int)` bytes for `matrix` to point to?

And why are you defining `void main()` rather than the correct `int main(void)`? `(void main()` is mostly useful as a way to detect books and tutorials written by authors who don't know the language very well.)

Comment: Thank you Keith.
matrix = malloc(sizeof(int *));
*matrix = malloc(sizeof(int));
Solved my problem.

Comment: You mean Herb Schildt, by any chance ;-?

Comment: @wildplasser: Yes, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not allocating memory properly. `matrix` is a pointer that points to a integer pointer not just an integer pointer.

The correct way to do this would be:

(Warning: I type this directly on the browser, do not use it in production)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int **matrix,i,j;
    matrix = (int **) malloc(sizeof(void *));
    *matrix = (int *) malloc(sizeof(void *));
    **matrix = 10;
    printf("%d", **matrix);

    free(*matrix);
    free(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

It is easier to understand what is going on by imagining how the memory would look like in each line ( address  | type | value {value_type}):

```
        int **matrix,i,j;
```

```
stack:
    matrix:  0x00 | &int ** | NULL {int **}
    i:       0x04 | &int    | GARBAGE {int}
    j:       0x08 | &int    | GARBAGE {int}
```

Because virtual memory, it is usual that Operative Systems initialize memory with 0 (or NULL) but as this is not granted it is bad programming to count with that.

```
        matrix = (int **) malloc(sizeof(void *));
```

malloc will return an address of an space on the heap:

```
stack:
    matrix:  0x00 | &int ** | 0xA0 {int **}
    i:       0x04 | &int    | GARBAGE {int}
    j:       0x08 | &int    | GARBAGE {int}
heap:
    *matrix: 0xA0 | &int *  | GARBAGE {int *}
```

```
        *matrix = (int *) malloc(sizeof(void *));
```

```
stack:
    matrix:  0x00 | &int ** | 0xA0 {int **}
    i:       0x04 | &int    | GARBAGE {int}
    j:       0x08 | &int    | GARBAGE {int}
heap:
    *matrix: 0xA0 | &int *  | 0xA4 {int *}
    **matrix:0xA4 | &int    | GARBAGE {int}
```

```
        **matrix = 10;
```

```
stack:
    matrix:  0x00 | &int ** | 0xA0 {int **}
    i:       0x04 | &int    | GARBAGE {int}
    j:       0x08 | &int    | GARBAGE {int}
heap:
    *matrix: 0xA0 | &int *  | 0xA4 {int *}
    **matrix:0xA4 | &int    | 10 {int}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sizeof(int)
```

stores size for and int, whilist

```
sizeof(*int)
```

stores size to a pointer to int. You are reserving the size of an `int` and not the size of an `*int`. This is what is causing the problems.

Also you should allocate the int to a *int pointer if you want also to do some real computations.

Comment: No, this is not the cause of the problem.